# AbiWord is launching on every reboot on ubuntu 15.04 gnome

Tags: gnome, 15.04

As the title says, AbiWord is launching every time after logging into my desktop without any user interaction. I've tried to find an entry in init.d but couldn't find something. This happens since the first day I installed ubuntu.

I found this [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/abiword/+bug/1432271), the only "answer" is

> My solution is simple uninstall Abiword. Libre is fine for my
>   purposes.

Does anybody know why this happens or where I could disable it?

Comment: "the only "answer" is ...My solution is simple uninstall Abiword. Libre is fine for my purposes. ..." isn't really correct because the answer provided by comment #10 in the bug worked for several people.